# How To Prevent Cookies From Being Created Under Different Hosts

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've run into a problem and I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.  Here is the scenario.

A user visits my website (www.MyWebSite.com) and clicks on a button that puts a cookie on their computer.  If I examined that cookie on their machine it would list the "host" as www.MyWebSite.com.

If the user then changes the URL in their browser to MyWebSite.com (without the www) reloads the page and then clicks on the button, a brand new cookie with the same name as the first cookie is created.  The host of this cookie is MywebSite.com

Obviously this is not good - beside two cookies with the same name, only the cookie with the corresponding URL address is being read by my program.

Can I force cookies to be created with the www host and/or can I force the page to be www or what???  What and how is the best way to prevent this problem?

Cookie Creation using VB.net

```
Response.Cookies("AAA")("bbb") = strABC
Response.Cookies("AAA").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For (obvious) security reasons you can only read cookies  that are set by the same domain the user requests. It doesn't matter if it is just a difference like in your example, or an entirely different domainname.

What you could do in this situation (it should improve your SEO as well), is redirect (301) all traffic from the site without www to the site with www.

If you're using IIS 7 or higher, you can find an example on how to do that with URL Rewrite here: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/11/27/iis-url-rewrite-rewriting-non-www-to-www.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That's for security reasons. Any subdomain of a host is considered to be another realm, another world.

If you want your cookies to be sent to your subdomains too, then start the `Host` attribute of the cookie with a `.`. In other words, set your cookie for `.MyWebSite.Com`.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path) for more information.